# Graphql error : "syntax error before: \"\\\"variables\\\"\""

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-hooks, apollo-client

I have connected the usQuery graphql hook

app.js:

```
function App() {

    const GET_RES = gql`

    query ($input: GetRaceResultsInput, $before: String, $after: String, $first: Int, $last: Int) {
        get_race_results(before: $before, after: $after, first: $first, last: $last, input: $input) {
            edges {
                cursor
                node {
                   country
                   city
                }
            }
            pageInfo {
                startCursor
                endCursor
                hasNextPage
                hasPreviousPage
            }
        }
    }
`;

const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_RES,{variables: {
    "first": 2,
    "input": {
        "onlyMyRacehorses": false,
        "distance": {
            "from": 1000,
            "to": 2400
        }
    }
}});
console.log(" ~ file: App.js ~ line 16 ~ loading", loading)
console.log(" ~ file: App.js ~ line 16 ~ error", error)
console.log(" ~ file: App.js ~ line 16 ~ data", data);

  return (
    <div className="view view-main">
      <div className="pages">
        <div data-page="about" className="page">
          <div className="page-content">
            
              <AppRouter />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Continuously getting this error :

> {"errors":[{"locations":[{"column":2,"line":1}],"message":"syntax error before: "\"variables\"""}]}

Any idea what's I am missing here?

And on insomnia getting this

[image]

server network tab
[image]

Comment: looks like BE/API problem ... does it work with playground [if build in and active] ?

Comment: its not provided in docs

Comment: https://docs.zed.run/racing/getraceresults#getraceresults

Comment: check required headers

Comment: headers: {
      ...headers,
      Authorization: `x-developer-secret ${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY_STRING}`,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      
    }

Comment: sending the required header

Comment: show real data - screenshot from network tab (covered/erased key), not code

Comment: You should probably refresh you secret token you just published in the server network picture :)

Comment: it is so big in picture you can only see one-fourth of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In query, should be getRaceResults(before: .......) instead of get_race_results(before.....)

Try:

```
query ($input: GetRaceResultsInput, $before: String, $after: String, $first: Int, $last: Int) {
      getRaceResults(before: $before, after: $after, first: $first, last: $last, input: $input) {
        edges {
          cursor
          node {
            country
            city
          }
        }
        pageInfo {
          startCursor
          endCursor
          hasNextPage
          hasPreviousPage
        }
      }
    }
```

variable:

```
{
    "first": 2,
    "input": {
        "onlyMyRacehorses": false,
        "distance": {
            "from": 1000,
            "to": 2400
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: some thing like this : get_race_results(before: $before, after:
it is already there

Comment: Replace "get_race_results" in query with "getRaceResults", in line 2 of query.

Comment: no change, i have checked their schema in insomnia, there I found the this one. well I have updated this but still same error

Comment: true, seems like there is a problem at zed.run's end when using distance variable, I get the same error in postman. Using time window instead works.  

{
 "first": 100,
    "after": null,
 "input": {
  "dates": {
            "from": "2021-04-16 21:01:00Z",
            "to": "2021-04-17 21:02:00Z"              
  }
 }
}

Comment: @S.Sid try now, seems like distance is working now, yeah?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233229/discussion-between-s-sid-and-howie).